# Why/when should I use std::unique/shared_ptr (std::vector<>) over just std::vector<>?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm a little bit confused about the main use of `std::unique/shared_ptr(std::vector<>)` when I can simply use a `std::vector<>`, which, as I know, is itself inherently a dynamic array. As I have also seen around, people say that there is no any performance difference between these two. So, based on all this, what is the point of using a smart pointer pointing to a container (in this case, a vector) instead of a vector alone?

Comment: Do you need to shared ownership of the vector ?

Comment: *people say that there is no any performance difference between these two* Whoever told you that lied, or didn't know what they were talking about.  `std::shared_ptr` is expensive and should only be used is you really need shared ownership.  What is your use case for your vector?

Comment: Which context? What is 'TYPE'?

Comment: whereas `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>>` might make sense, I don't see the point of `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<T>>`.

Comment: Thank you. No, my problem is not sharing the object (that's why I just added the unique). I just wanted to know when we can have a dynamically allocated vector/array, why should we use smart pointers whose, as I know, main application is dynamic allocation?

Comment: @Jarod42 I am not even sure how to read the question. Is OP asking about `std::vector<ptrT>` or `ptrT<std:vector<>>`?

Comment: I edited the text to better clarify things. The context is also image processing. So, handling big data (lots of images) is the main concern.

Comment: There really isn't reason to dynamically allocate a vector.  You don't get anything out of it.  There might be some use cases but they elude me at present.

Comment: @NathanOliver only in shared ownership scenarios. But since I believe legitimate shared ownership scenarios are really rare, I think, dynamic allocation of vector is really-rarely useful thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be using `std::shared_ptr` unless you need the specific "shared ownership" semantics associated with `std::shared_ptr`. If you need a smart pointer, you should default to `std::unique_ptr` by default, and only switch away from it in the scenario where you expressly find that you need to.

Secondly: *ostensibly*, the reason to prefer `std::unique_ptr<TYPE>` over `TYPE` is if you plan to move the object around a lot. This is the common design paradigm for large objects that are either unmovable, or otherwise expensive to move—i.e. they implemented a Copy Constructor and didn't implement a Move Constructor, so moves are forced to behave like a Copy.

`std::vector`, however, does have relatively efficient move semantics: if you move a `std::vector` around, regardless of how complex its contained types are, the move only constitutes a couple of pointer swaps. There's no real risk that moving a `std::vector` will incur a large amount of computational complexity. Even in the scenario where you're overriding a previously allocated array (invoking the Destructors of all objects in the vector), you'd still have that complexity if you were using `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<TYPE>>` instead, saving you nothing.

There are two advantages to `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<TYPE>>`. The first of which is that it gets rid of the implicit copy constructor; maybe you want to enforce to maintaining programmers that the object shouldn't be copied. But that's a pretty niche use. The other advantage is that it allows you to stipulate the scenario where there's no vector, i.e. `vec.size() == 0` is a different condition than `doesNotExist(vec)`. But even in that scenario, you should be preferring `std::optional<std::vector>` instead, which better conveys through the code the intent of the object. Granted, `std::optional` is only available in C++17→ Code, so maybe you're in an environment that hasn't implemented it yet. But otherwise, there's little reason to use `std::unique_ptr<std::vector>`.

So in general, I don't believe there are practical uses for `std::unique_ptr<std::vector>`. There's no practical performance difference between it and `std::vector`, and using it will just make your code needlessly complex.

Comment: Yeah, there is no need to convey optionality with unique_ptr. There are plenty of C++14 conforming implementations of optional, so one can just use one of those.

Comment: Examine what happens when you have a throwing move ctor/assign in the type stored in the vector..

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont You're going to have to elaborate on what you mean, because from context, it's not clear how this is supposed to improve my answer.

Comment: @Xirema What happens to `std::vector<TypeThatCanThrowOnAMove>` when you try to move-assign it?  What happens to `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<TypeThatCanThrowOnAMove>>`?  It is a corner case, but a difference.